# ¿Cómo crear una clase para cambiar color de botones en formularios C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿cómo podría hacer para crear una clase que contenga los eventos `MouseEnter` y `MouseLeave` para cambiar el color de los botones en lugar de poner el código para cambiar el color en cada botón y evitar que el código del formulario se haga demasiado extenso?

Por ejemplo, tengo este código dentro del evento `MouseEnter`, y lo que yo quiero es hacerlo en una clase para no llenar con muchas líneas de código el *form*:

```
private void btnAdd_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    btn.Image = GV100319.Properties.Resources.add_1;
    btn.BackColor = Color.White;
    btn.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(69, 90, 100);
    btn.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold);
}

private void btnAdd_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    btn.Image = GV100319.Properties.Resources.add;
    btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(69, 90, 100);
    btn.ForeColor = Color.White;
    btn.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
}
```

Comment: Porque no lo haces con javascript o jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un método estático (dos en realidad) que haga las asignaciones apropiadas, e incluso convertirlo en un método de extensión para mayor comodidad en la llamada al mismo. O mejor, creas un método de extensión parametrizado y dos métodos que deleguen en el primero, pero utilizando valores pre definidos.

```
public static class ExtensionesBoton
{
    public static void Toggle(this Button boton, Image imagen, Color fondo, Color frente, Font fuente)
    {
        boton.Image = imagen;
        boton.BackColor = fondo;
        boton.ForeColor = frente;
        boton.Font = fuente;
    }

    public static void RatonEntrando(this Button boton)
        => boton.Toggle(GV100319.Properties.Resources.add_1,
            Color.White,
            Color.FromArgb(69, 90, 100),
            new Font("Segoe UI", 9, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold));

    public static void RatonSaliendo(this Button boton)
        => boton.Toggle(GV100319.Properties.Resources.add,
            Color.FromArgb(69, 90, 100),
            Color.White,
            new Font("Segoe UI", 8, FontStyle.Regular));
}
```

A partir de aquí solo tienes que hacer las llamadas a los métodos adecuados, sin repetir el código de las mismas.

```
private void btnAdd_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button boton = sender as Button;
    boton.RatonEntrando();
}

private void btnAdd_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button boton = sender as Button;
    boton.RatonSaliendo();
}
```

Puedes incluso hacer un casting directo si el contexto te lo permite (si sabes que no va a saltar una excepción), con lo que el código de tus botones se reduciría aún más.

```
private void btnAdd_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => ((Button)sender).RatonEntrando();

private void btnAdd_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    => ((Button)sender).RatonSaliendo();
```

Otra opción sería colocar en el propio método estático el código del casting, creando una versión del mismo que acepte un objeto de tipo `object`.

```
public static class ExtensionesBoton
{
    // Métodos antes introducidos

    public static void RatonEntrando(this object objeto)
    {
        Button boton = objeto as Button;
        if (boton == null) /* Alguna acción */;
        else boton.RatonEntrando();
    }

    public static void RatonSaliendo(this object objeto)
    {
        Button boton = objeto as Button;
        if (boton == null) /* Alguna acción */;
        else boton.RatonSaliendo();
    }
}
```

El código de los botones quedaría así:

```
private void btnAdd_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) => sender.RatonEntrando();

private void btnAdd_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) => sender.RatonSaliendo();
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, me ha funcionado mucho!!